# ajaxSubmit help - IE9 not loading target or submitting twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, internet-explorer-9

I have a form that is being submitted using the jQuery Form Plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). There are actually two problems that I'm running into. With this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var options = {
        target: "#result",
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,
        forceSync: true
    };

    $("#testForm").submit(function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);

        return false;
    });

});
```

The form submits, but the form remains visible like nothing was submitted. In Chrome, Firefox, etc, the form goes away and a success page comes up. In IE9, nothing happens, but the form is submitted correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        var options = {
            target: "#result",
            beforeSubmit: showRequest,
            forceSync: true
        };

        $("#testForm").submit(function() {
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);

            return true;
        });

    });
```

With the return value in .submit() set to true, the form goes away and the success page loads, but the form is submitted twice.

In both cases, the form is submitted correctly in Chrome and Firefox.

Any hints as to what I am doing incorrectly? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="jquery_form.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

                $('#AddVersion').submit(function() {
                    var options = {
                        url:        'upload.php',
                        success:    showResponse
                    };
                    // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first
                    // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit
                    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
                    console.log($(this));
                    //alert("I am herer");

                    // !!! Important !!!
                    // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation
                    return false;

                });

                function showResponse(data) {
                alert('Total files uploaded are :'+data);
                //alert('uploaded successfully');
            }
            });
</script>
                        <form role="form" id="AddVersion" name="AddVersion"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="htmls_new" name="htmls_new" value="1" /> 

                              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr style="font-size:12pt;" class="warning">
                                        <td><p class="text-info">Select File(s)</p></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <input id="input_V_File" name="input_V_File[]" type="file" class="" form="AddVersion" multiple/>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="floatRight">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>&nbsp;
                                                <input type="submit" form-action="#" form="AddVersion" class="btn btn-success floatRight" value="Submit" />
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```